# Is there a pre-built function to add the elements in two arrays?

Tags: ruby

If I have two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
```

Is there a pre-built function to add the two arrays to give

```
c = a + b = [3,5,7]
```

i.e. add the values of each element in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you ask is:

```
[1,2,3].zip([2,3,4]).map{|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

it works even with more arrays

```
[1,2,3].zip([2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]).map{|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, there isn't one method for this. But you can combine `zip` and `map` like this:

```
c = a.zip(b).map {|a,b| a+b}
```

Answer (score 6):

That looks a lot like vector addition. Here's one way to accomplish that:

```
require 'matrix'

a = Vector[1,2,3]
b = Vector[2,3,4]

puts a+b
#=> Vector[3,5,7]
```

Simply use `to_a` on a Vector to get an array.